# Python cbor2 encode float in preferred (efficient) format

Tags: python, cbor

The CBOR docs state that the most efficient (less number of bytes) encoding should be preferred.

floats can be encoded as 64-bit floats, or with extensions as 32-bit, 16-bit, BigFloat or DecimalFloat formats.

Stanards 64-bit encoding uses 9 bytes.  Some floating values can take much less space if using an alterantive format (e.g the values 0.0, 1.0, 1.5 can be represented as 4 bytes using BigFloats).

Some values are better represented as standard floats (e.g. 0.123456789 is represented by 9 bytes as 64-bit float or 29 bytes with BigFloats.

The `cbor2` python library supports BigFloats if using the `Decimal` type, or the float if using the `float` type.

How can I get `cbor2` to automatically emit the most efficient type depending on the actual value?

I have tried various arbitrary values using `cbor2.dumps()`.  `floats` are always encoded as CBOR floats, and `Decimal` types are alwasy encoded as CBOR BigFloats.

```py
>>> x=0.0 ; x ; d1 = dumps(x) ; d1 ; len(d1) ; dx = Decimal(x) ; d2 = dumps(dx) ; d2 ; len(d2)
0.0
b'\xfb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
9
b'\xc4\x82\x00\x00'
4

>>> x=1.0 ; x ; d1 = dumps(x) ; d1 ; len(d1) ; dx = Decimal(x) ; d2 = dumps(dx) ; d2 ; len(d2)
1.0
b'\xfb?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
9
b'\xc4\x82\x00\x01'
4

>>> x=1.5 ; x ; d1 = dumps(x) ; d1 ; len(d1) ; dx = Decimal(x) ; d2 = dumps(dx) ; d2 ; len(d2)
1.5
b'\xfb?\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
9
b'\xc4\x82 \x0f'
4

>>> x=0.123456789 ; x ; d1 = dumps(x) ; d1 ; len(d1) ; dx = Decimal(x) ; d2 = dumps(dx) ; d2 ; len(d2)
0.123456789
b'\xfb?\xbf\x9a\xdd79c_'
9
b'\xc4\x8287\xc2W\x80\xe5\x18Js\xc0\xe4\x8f-\xf1\xc9\xf0\x90\xf4u%+\x93\xa7\n\x88\xa2?'
29
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer is a combination of using the `canonical=True` argument to `dumps()` and casting the floats to lower precision floats (using `numpy`) where suitable (if any loss of precision is tolerable/acceptable).

NOTE: have to cast back to python float as `cbor` can't encode `numpy` classes at the momement.

```py
>>> x=0.123456789 ; x ; d1=dumps(x, canonical=True) ; d1 ; len(d1)
0.123456789
b'\xfb?\xbf\x9a\xdd79c_'
9

>>> x=float( np.float32( 0.123456789 ) ) ; x ; d1=dumps(x, canonical=True) ; d1 ; len(d1)
0.12345679104328156
b'\xfa=\xfc\xd6\xea'
5

>>> x=float( np.float16( 0.123456789 ) ) ; x ; d1=dumps(x, canonical=True) ; d1 ; len(d1)
0.12347412109375
b'\xf9/\xe7'
3
```